Setting [core]executor=KubernetesExecutor is not permitted
I am trying to configure Kubernetes Executor for the Composer Instance.
However, I am getting the below error:
Setting [core]executor=KubernetesExecutor is not permitted., badRequest
I am on Composer version 2.4.6 and Airflow version 2.6.3. As per this blocked configuration. I am on right version where in I should be able to override this config. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?
Reference: Autoscaling Google Cloud Composer

So even though for latest composer version, core-executor isn't blocked conifguration anymore. It doesn't allow KubernetesExecutor as a permitted value. Currently, it only allows CeleryKubernetesExecutor as the value for core-executor config. Apart from the default one.
